# Listening to a * address on port 11111

Tags: java

I have tried this (sorry for my dumbness)

```
InetAddress inet=InetAddress.getByName("*");
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(11111,0,inet);
```

But that is wrong. I would like my application to listen to *:11111.

Thank you for any hints.

Sorry my title misleads you, I update to fix it

Comment: By *all ports* do you mean *all interfaces*? Like WiFi, eth0, localhost...

Comment: Thank you I update my title, sorry about the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(11111,0,null);`

From docs of ServerSocket:

> The bindAddr argument can be used on a multi-homed host for a ServerSocket that will only accept connect requests to one of its addresses. If bindAddr is null, it will default accepting connections on any/all local addresses.

Comment: @kinjal: I don't know, but it would make it more complicated, and I see no reason for that. It _would_ be interesting to try if just `new ServerSocket(11111)` works though...